# GridView does not bind with datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

What is the problem with the following code? The GridView GridView1 does not show up on page at all.

```
  public void display_range_mark()
    {
        int from = int.Parse(ddl_from_mark.SelectedValue.ToString());
        int to = int.Parse(ddl_to_mark.SelectedIndex.ToString());
        DataTable dt=Data.DoSomthing(string.Format("select ts.Name,ts.FamilyName,ts.Id_student,td.Name,tn.NomreAdad from tblStudent ts,tblDars td,tblNomre tn where tn.NomreAdad>='{0}' AND tn.NomreAdad<='{1}' AND ts.Id=tn.Id_student AND td.Id=tn.Id_dars",from,to));
        //DataTable data = Data.DoSomthing(string.Format("select t.Name,t.Id from tblStd t where t.DateSabt='{0}'", p.GetYear(DateTime.Now)));
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "نام";
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = "نام خانوادگی";
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Text = "شماره دانش آموزی";
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Text = "درس";
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Text = "نمره";
        GridView1.DataBind();



    }
```

I am getting this error: 
**Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
The error occurs at this line:

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "نام";
```

By the way, the code for Data.DoSomthing is as folllows (It is located within class *Database*):

```
 SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=School;Integrated Security=True");



public DataTable DoSomthing(string text)
    {
        sc.Open();
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = sc;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = text;

            SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            sd.Fill(data);
            if (data.Rows.Count == 0)
                data = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sc.Close();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sc.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sc.Close();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Have you trued to call the `GridView1.DataBind();` right after the `GridView1.DataSource = dt;`?

Comment: Try setting the cell text after you databind. Or maybe you should use `GridView1.Columns[x].HeaderText=''` instead.

Comment: @TasosK. Yes I have tried it. Didn't work either

Comment: Then, what about the error message. It says "null reference", whereas I don't think it is null object assignment.

Comment: @misaq, please check my answer. The Null reference is because there is no gridview to look for header. The Gridview is null until it is populated.

Comment: Did you run the query in SSMS and check if values are returned ? And did you check from and to variable in VS debug mode ?

Comment: @Partha, I just did it. I found my returned datatable is null. But in SSMS, it works fine. I don't know where the mess is :(

Comment: Then it must be the connection. Check if you are connection is done before proceeding. Refer this: http://www.aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/SQL/TestSQLConnection.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the connection object to connect to the database and fetch values ?

The way to do this:

```
string query="select ts.Name,ts.FamilyName,ts.Id_student,td.Name,tn.NomreAdad from     tblStudent ts,tblDars     td,tblNomre tn where tn.NomreAdad>=@from AND tn.NomreAdad<=@to AND ts.Id=tn.Id_student AND td.Id=tn.Id_dars";

//Create Sqlconnection object
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
//open the connection
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
//To avoid sql injection using parameters
sda.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@from",from);
sda.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@to",to);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Everything was OK! It didn't populate the datatable because there was simply no matches in the database. By changing values to and from, it worked finally. Also, as it was said within comments, it seemed necessary for data.DataBind() to precede column header assignments

Comment: Oh cool. That is why I asked you to run in debug mode. And also add parameters as I added to command to avoid SQL injection. Dont know why it was down voted